# Using sed over ssh to add item to list

Tags: ssh, sed, nested

I need to modify a Python file on a remote server, and I'm stuck formatting a sed command inside an ssh.

The file to be modified has this line

> `my_list = ["item1"]`

and I need to change it to include another item:

> `my_list = ["item1", "item2"]`

Here's what I have:

> `ssh user@host 'sed -i \'s/my_list = \[\\"item1\\"]/my_list = \[\\"item1\\", \\"item2\\"]/\' path/to/file'`

The number of escapes required for quotes and open brackets is throwing me off since it's within an ssh.
I'd appreciate a hand if anyone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest single quotes, and you can't escape single quotes inside single quotes. The simplest solution by far in this particular case is to just quote less; there is nothing in `sed` or `-i` which requires quoting. But because both your local shell and the remote shell processes the command line, you need two layers of quoting.

```sh
ssh user@host sed -i "'s/my_list = \\[\"item1\"]/my_list = [\"item1\", \"item2\"]/'" path/to/file
```

Perhaps notice also that the replacement string is just a string, so there is no need to escape the `[` there.

For debugging these things, try

```sh
ssh user@host printf '%s\\n' sed -i "'s/my_list = \\[\"item1\"]/my_list = [\"item1\", \"item2\"]/'" path/to/file
```

to see the command line split up into one token per line on the remote host.

Fundamentally, you should probably change the remote Python script to read its input in a standard format like JSON or YAML. Programs which write programs are a powerful tool, but unsophisticated programs which modify existing programs are often going to end up brittle and hard to debug.